# jQuery ui dialog add a help icon in the titlebar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'd like to add a help icon in the title bar (right corner) of the JQuery UI dialog box.

I started from the default dialog demo

```
$('span.OK').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ $( "#dialog" ).dialog(); }, 100);
});
```

here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/survivant/cyFxp/3/

I found that there is a default help icon in the theme, but I'm not sure how to display it in the title bar.

The goal is to have a ? (help) button display beside the X (close) button.  When I click on it, I want a popup to open (probably another dialog) that will show the help.

EDIT

Thanks to the answers given, I have now a help icon that will show an alert when clicked.  However, when hovering over this icon, the cursor is a "move" cursor instead of a "pointer" cursor like the close button.

How can I make prevent the "move" cursor in favor of the "pointer" cursor?

PS.  the demo in the answer below works in jsbin, but my demo in jsfiddle doesn't work.

Comment: You can use this simple JQuery UI plugin: https://github.com/ExSoax/jQuery-UI-Dialog-Custom-Titlebar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [dialogClass property](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-dialogClass) of jquery ui dialog to give a class to your dialog. Than you can search for that class and append `ui-icon-help` to dialogs titlebar. Check this fiddle:

[Demo fiddle](http://jsbin.com/iwiloc/2/edit)

Now you can set necessary events on the icon according to your need.

Hope this is what you are looking for!

**EDIT**

I have checked your fiddle and update it, check this :

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyFxp/4/)

Comment: almost, if I want to add a event handler on this new span, the hover show the Move cursor.  I was able to show a popup with this $("#iconhelp").click(function(){
   alert('help');
});

Comment: merci,  thanks that will do the job.  It's really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I thought this might help someone.

If you are creating a dialog on the fly (without creating a dialog from an existing HTML element), the easiest way I've found is by using the dialog's "open" event (http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open) to prepend (or append) your icon to the title.

The following example uses font-awesome icons with Twitter Bootstrap, but you can use any icon or image you want for the myIcon variable:

```
var myIcon   =  '<i class="icon icon-flag-checkered icon-large pull-left"></i>';       
var myDialog = $('<div title="ALMOST DONE!">'
    + 'Your Text/HTML Here'
    + '</div>');
myDialog.dialog({
    resizable   : false,
    height      : 'auto',
    open        : function(){
        $(this)
        .parent()
        .children(".ui-dialog-titlebar")
        .prepend(myIcon);
    },
    buttons     : {
        "Any Button"    : function(){
            alert('Yep, you clicked it.')
        },
        "OK"    : function(){
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

example at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/drb26/2/

Comment: This doesn't add buttons to the title bar (as OP requested) but to the bottom of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I added an "icon" option to jQuery UI Dialog. Full modified code can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/jaysudo/02nwzg8g/1/

```
/*!
 * jQuery UI Dialog 1.11.4

 *
 * Copyright jQuery Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license.

 *
 * Modified by: Jay Sudo <jay@jaysudo.com>
 * 05/11/2015
 *

 */


var dialog = $.widget( "ui.dialog", {
    version: "1.11.4",
    options: {
        icon: null,
        appendTo: "body",
        autoOpen: true,
        buttons: [],
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeText: "Close",
        dialogClass: "",
        draggable: true,
        hide: null,
        height: "auto",
        maxHeight: null,
        maxWidth: null,
        minHeight: 150,
        minWidth: 150,
        modal: false,
        position: {
            my: "center",
            at: "center",
            of: window,
            collision: "fit",
            // Ensure the titlebar is always visible
            using: function( pos ) {
                var topOffset = $( this ).css( pos ).offset().top;
                if ( topOffset < 0 ) {
                    $( this ).css( "top", pos.top - topOffset );
                }
            }
        },
        resizable: true,
        show: null,
        title: null,
        width: 300,

        // callbacks
        beforeClose: null,
        close: null,
        drag: null,
        dragStart: null,
        dragStop: null,
        focus: null,
        open: null,
        resize: null,
        resizeStart: null,
        resizeStop: null
    },

    sizeRelatedOptions: {
        buttons: true,
        height: true,
        maxHeight: true,
        maxWidth: true,
        minHeight: true,
        minWidth: true,
        width: true
    },

    resizableRelatedOptions: {
        maxHeight: true,
        maxWidth: true,
        minHeight: true,
        minWidth: true
    },

    _create: function() {
        this.originalCss = {
            display: this.element[ 0 ].style.display,
            width: this.element[ 0 ].style.width,
            minHeight: this.element[ 0 ].style.minHeight,
            maxHeight: this.element[ 0 ].style.maxHeight,
            height: this.element[ 0 ].style.height
        };
        this.originalPosition = {
            parent: this.element.parent(),
            index: this.element.parent().children().index( this.element )
        };
        this.originalTitle = this.element.attr( "title" );
        this.options.title = this.options.title || this.originalTitle;
        this.options.icon = this.options.icon || "ui-icon-info";

        this._createWrapper();

        this.element
            .show()
            .removeAttr( "title" )
            .addClass( "ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" )
            .appendTo( this.uiDialog );

        this._createTitlebar();
        this._createButtonPane();

        if ( this.options.draggable && $.fn.draggable ) {
            this._makeDraggable();
        }
        if ( this.options.resizable && $.fn.resizable ) {
            this._makeResizable();
        }

        this._isOpen = false;

        this._trackFocus();
    },

    _init: function() {
        if ( this.options.autoOpen ) {
            this.open();
        }
    },

    _appendTo: function() {
        var element = this.options.appendTo;
        if ( element && (element.jquery || element.nodeType) ) {
            return $( element );
        }
        return this.document.find( element || "body" ).eq( 0 );
    },

    _destroy: function() {
        var next,
            originalPosition = this.originalPosition;

        this._untrackInstance();
        this._destroyOverlay();

        this.element
            .removeUniqueId()
            .removeClass( "ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" )
            .css( this.originalCss )
            // Without detaching first, the following becomes really slow
            .detach();

        this.uiDialog.stop( true, true ).remove();

        if ( this.originalTitle ) {
            this.element.attr( "title", this.originalTitle );
        }

        next = originalPosition.parent.children().eq( originalPosition.index );
        // Don't try to place the dialog next to itself (#8613)
        if ( next.length && next[ 0 ] !== this.element[ 0 ] ) {
            next.before( this.element );
        } else {
            originalPosition.parent.append( this.element );
        }
    },

    widget: function() {
        return this.uiDialog;
    },

    disable: $.noop,
    enable: $.noop,

    close: function( event ) {
        var activeElement,
            that = this;

        if ( !this._isOpen || this._trigger( "beforeClose", event ) === false ) {
            return;
        }

        this._isOpen = false;
        this._focusedElement = null;
        this._destroyOverlay();
        this._untrackInstance();

        if ( !this.opener.filter( ":focusable" ).focus().length ) {

            // support: IE9
            // IE9 throws an "Unspecified error" accessing document.activeElement from an <iframe>
            try {
                activeElement = this.document[ 0 ].activeElement;

                // Support: IE9, IE10
                // If the <body> is blurred, IE will switch windows, see #4520
                if ( activeElement && activeElement.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== "body" ) {

                    // Hiding a focused element doesn't trigger blur in WebKit
                    // so in case we have nothing to focus on, explicitly blur the active element
                    // https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47182
                    $( activeElement ).blur();
                }
            } catch ( error ) {}
        }

        this._hide( this.uiDialog, this.options.hide, function() {
            that._trigger( "close", event );
        });
    },

    isOpen: function() {
        return this._isOpen;
    },

    moveToTop: function() {
        this._moveToTop();
    },

    _moveToTop: function( event, silent ) {
        var moved = false,
            zIndices = this.uiDialog.siblings( ".ui-front:visible" ).map(function() {
                return +$( this ).css( "z-index" );
            }).get(),
            zIndexMax = Math.max.apply( null, zIndices );

        if ( zIndexMax >= +this.uiDialog.css( "z-index" ) ) {
            this.uiDialog.css( "z-index", zIndexMax + 1 );
            moved = true;
        }

        if ( moved && !silent ) {
            this._trigger( "focus", event );
        }
        return moved;
    },

    open: function() {
        var that = this;
        if ( this._isOpen ) {
            if ( this._moveToTop() ) {
                this._focusTabbable();
            }
            return;
        }

        this._isOpen = true;
        this.opener = $( this.document[ 0 ].activeElement );

        this._size();
        this._position();
        this._createOverlay();
        this._moveToTop( null, true );

        // Ensure the overlay is moved to the top with the dialog, but only when
        // opening. The overlay shouldn't move after the dialog is open so that
        // modeless dialogs opened after the modal dialog stack properly.
        if ( this.overlay ) {
            this.overlay.css( "z-index", this.uiDialog.css( "z-index" ) - 1 );
        }

        this._show( this.uiDialog, this.options.show, function() {
            that._focusTabbable();
            that._trigger( "focus" );
        });

        // Track the dialog immediately upon openening in case a focus event
        // somehow occurs outside of the dialog before an element inside the
        // dialog is focused (#10152)
        this._makeFocusTarget();

        this._trigger( "open" );
    },

    _focusTabbable: function() {
        // Set focus to the first match:
        // 1. An element that was focused previously
        // 2. First element inside the dialog matching [autofocus]
        // 3. Tabbable element inside the content element
        // 4. Tabbable element inside the buttonpane
        // 5. The close button
        // 6. The dialog itself
        var hasFocus = this._focusedElement;
        if ( !hasFocus ) {
            hasFocus = this.element.find( "[autofocus]" );
        }
        if ( !hasFocus.length ) {
            hasFocus = this.element.find( ":tabbable" );
        }
        if ( !hasFocus.length ) {
            hasFocus = this.uiDialogButtonPane.find( ":tabbable" );
        }
        if ( !hasFocus.length ) {
            hasFocus = this.uiDialogTitlebarClose.filter( ":tabbable" );
        }
        if ( !hasFocus.length ) {
            hasFocus = this.uiDialog;
        }
        hasFocus.eq( 0 ).focus();
    },

    _keepFocus: function( event ) {
        function checkFocus() {
            var activeElement = this.document[0].activeElement,
                isActive = this.uiDialog[0] === activeElement ||
                    $.contains( this.uiDialog[0], activeElement );
            if ( !isActive ) {
                this._focusTabbable();
            }
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        checkFocus.call( this );
        // support: IE
        // IE <= 8 doesn't prevent moving focus even with event.preventDefault()
        // so we check again later
        this._delay( checkFocus );
    },

    _createWrapper: function() {
        this.uiDialog = $("<div>")
            .addClass( "ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front " +
                this.options.dialogClass )
            .hide()
            .attr({
                // Setting tabIndex makes the div focusable
                tabIndex: -1,
                role: "dialog"
            })
            .appendTo( this._appendTo() );

        this._on( this.uiDialog, {
            keydown: function( event ) {
                if ( this.options.closeOnEscape && !event.isDefaultPrevented() && event.keyCode &&
                        event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE ) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    this.close( event );
                    return;
                }

                // prevent tabbing out of dialogs
                if ( event.keyCode !== $.ui.keyCode.TAB || event.isDefaultPrevented() ) {
                    return;
                }
                var tabbables = this.uiDialog.find( ":tabbable" ),
                    first = tabbables.filter( ":first" ),
                    last = tabbables.filter( ":last" );

                if ( ( event.target === last[0] || event.target === this.uiDialog[0] ) && !event.shiftKey ) {
                    this._delay(function() {
                        first.focus();
                    });
                    event.preventDefault();
                } else if ( ( event.target === first[0] || event.target === this.uiDialog[0] ) && event.shiftKey ) {
                    this._delay(function() {
                        last.focus();
                    });
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            },
            mousedown: function( event ) {
                if ( this._moveToTop( event ) ) {
                    this._focusTabbable();
                }
            }
        });

        // We assume that any existing aria-describedby attribute means
        // that the dialog content is marked up properly
        // otherwise we brute force the content as the description
        if ( !this.element.find( "[aria-describedby]" ).length ) {
            this.uiDialog.attr({
                "aria-describedby": this.element.uniqueId().attr( "id" )
            });
        }
    },

    _createTitlebar: function() {
        var uiDialogTitle;

        this.uiDialogTitlebar = $( "<div>" )
            .addClass( "ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" )
            .prependTo( this.uiDialog );
        this._on( this.uiDialogTitlebar, {
            mousedown: function( event ) {
                // Don't prevent click on close button (#8838)
                // Focusing a dialog that is partially scrolled out of view
                // causes the browser to scroll it into view, preventing the click event
                if ( !$( event.target ).closest( ".ui-dialog-titlebar-close" ) ) {
                    // Dialog isn't getting focus when dragging (#8063)
                    this.uiDialog.focus();
                }
            }
        });

        // support: IE
        // Use type="button" to prevent enter keypresses in textboxes from closing the
        // dialog in IE (#9312)
        this.uiDialogTitlebarClose = $( "<button type='button'></button>" )
            .button({
                label: this.options.closeText,
                icons: {
                    primary: "ui-icon-closethick"
                },
                text: false
            })
            .addClass( "ui-dialog-titlebar-close" )
            .appendTo( this.uiDialogTitlebar );
        this._on( this.uiDialogTitlebarClose, {
            click: function( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                this.close( event );
            }
        });

        uiDialogTitle = $( "<span>" )
            .uniqueId()
            .addClass( "ui-dialog-title" )
            .prependTo( this.uiDialogTitlebar );
        this._title( uiDialogTitle );


        this.uiDialog.attr({
            "aria-labelledby": uiDialogTitle.attr( "id" )
        });
    },

    _title: function( title ) {
        var uiDialogTitleIcon = $( "<span>" )
            .uniqueId()
            .addClass( "ui-icon " + this.options.icon)
            .css( {"display": "inline-block"} );

        if ( !this.options.title ) {
            title.html( "&#160;" );
        }
        title.html(uiDialogTitleIcon[0].outerHTML + " " + this.options.title );
    },

    _createButtonPane: function() {
        this.uiDialogButtonPane = $( "<div>" )
            .addClass( "ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix" );

        this.uiButtonSet = $( "<div>" )
            .addClass( "ui-dialog-buttonset" )
            .appendTo( this.uiDialogButtonPane );

        this._createButtons();
    },

    _createButtons: function() {
        var that = this,
            buttons = this.options.buttons;

        // if we already have a button pane, remove it
        this.uiDialogButtonPane.remove();
        this.uiButtonSet.empty();

        if ( $.isEmptyObject( buttons ) || ($.isArray( buttons ) && !buttons.length) ) {
            this.uiDialog.removeClass( "ui-dialog-buttons" );
            return;
        }

        $.each( buttons, function( name, props ) {
            var click, buttonOptions;
            props = $.isFunction( props ) ?
                { click: props, text: name } :
                props;
            // Default to a non-submitting button
            props = $.extend( { type: "button" }, props );
            // Change the context for the click callback to be the main element
            click = props.click;
            props.click = function() {
                click.apply( that.element[ 0 ], arguments );
            };
            buttonOptions = {
                icons: props.icons,
                text: props.showText
            };
            delete props.icons;
            delete props.showText;
            $( "<button></button>", props )
                .button( buttonOptions )
                .appendTo( that.uiButtonSet );
        });
        this.uiDialog.addClass( "ui-dialog-buttons" );
        this.uiDialogButtonPane.appendTo( this.uiDialog );
    },

    _makeDraggable: function() {
        var that = this,
            options = this.options;

        function filteredUi( ui ) {
            return {
                position: ui.position,
                offset: ui.offset
            };
        }

        this.uiDialog.draggable({
            cancel: ".ui-dialog-content, .ui-dialog-titlebar-close",
            handle: ".ui-dialog-titlebar",
            containment: "document",
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                $( this ).addClass( "ui-dialog-dragging" );
                that._blockFrames();
                that._trigger( "dragStart", event, filteredUi( ui ) );
            },
            drag: function( event, ui ) {
                that._trigger( "drag", event, filteredUi( ui ) );
            },
            stop: function( event, ui ) {
                var left = ui.offset.left - that.document.scrollLeft(),
                    top = ui.offset.top - that.document.scrollTop();

                options.position = {
                    my: "left top",
                    at: "left" + (left >= 0 ? "+" : "") + left + " " +
                        "top" + (top >= 0 ? "+" : "") + top,
                    of: that.window
                };
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-dialog-dragging" );
                that._unblockFrames();
                that._trigger( "dragStop", event, filteredUi( ui ) );
            }
        });
    },

    _makeResizable: function() {
        var that = this,
            options = this.options,
            handles = options.resizable,
            // .ui-resizable has position: relative defined in the stylesheet
            // but dialogs have to use absolute or fixed positioning
            position = this.uiDialog.css("position"),
            resizeHandles = typeof handles === "string" ?
                handles :
                "n,e,s,w,se,sw,ne,nw";

        function filteredUi( ui ) {
            return {
                originalPosition: ui.originalPosition,
                originalSize: ui.originalSize,
                position: ui.position,
                size: ui.size
            };
        }

        this.uiDialog.resizable({
            cancel: ".ui-dialog-content",
            containment: "document",
            alsoResize: this.element,
            maxWidth: options.maxWidth,
            maxHeight: options.maxHeight,
            minWidth: options.minWidth,
            minHeight: this._minHeight(),
            handles: resizeHandles,
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                $( this ).addClass( "ui-dialog-resizing" );
                that._blockFrames();
                that._trigger( "resizeStart", event, filteredUi( ui ) );
            },
            resize: function( event, ui ) {
                that._trigger( "resize", event, filteredUi( ui ) );
            },
            stop: function( event, ui ) {
                var offset = that.uiDialog.offset(),
                    left = offset.left - that.document.scrollLeft(),
                    top = offset.top - that.document.scrollTop();

                options.height = that.uiDialog.height();
                options.width = that.uiDialog.width();
                options.position = {
                    my: "left top",
                    at: "left" + (left >= 0 ? "+" : "") + left + " " +
                        "top" + (top >= 0 ? "+" : "") + top,
                    of: that.window
                };
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-dialog-resizing" );
                that._unblockFrames();
                that._trigger( "resizeStop", event, filteredUi( ui ) );
            }
        })
        .css( "position", position );
    },

    _trackFocus: function() {
        this._on( this.widget(), {
            focusin: function( event ) {
                this._makeFocusTarget();
                this._focusedElement = $( event.target );
            }
        });
    },

    _makeFocusTarget: function() {
        this._untrackInstance();
        this._trackingInstances().unshift( this );
    },

    _untrackInstance: function() {
        var instances = this._trackingInstances(),
            exists = $.inArray( this, instances );
        if ( exists !== -1 ) {
            instances.splice( exists, 1 );
        }
    },

    _trackingInstances: function() {
        var instances = this.document.data( "ui-dialog-instances" );
        if ( !instances ) {
            instances = [];
            this.document.data( "ui-dialog-instances", instances );
        }
        return instances;
    },

    _minHeight: function() {
        var options = this.options;

        return options.height === "auto" ?
            options.minHeight :
            Math.min( options.minHeight, options.height );
    },

    _position: function() {
        // Need to show the dialog to get the actual offset in the position plugin
        var isVisible = this.uiDialog.is( ":visible" );
        if ( !isVisible ) {
            this.uiDialog.show();
        }
        this.uiDialog.position( this.options.position );
        if ( !isVisible ) {
            this.uiDialog.hide();
        }
    },

    _setOptions: function( options ) {
        var that = this,
            resize = false,
            resizableOptions = {};

        $.each( options, function( key, value ) {
            that._setOption( key, value );

            if ( key in that.sizeRelatedOptions ) {
                resize = true;
            }
            if ( key in that.resizableRelatedOptions ) {
                resizableOptions[ key ] = value;
            }
        });

        if ( resize ) {
            this._size();
            this._position();
        }
        if ( this.uiDialog.is( ":data(ui-resizable)" ) ) {
            this.uiDialog.resizable( "option", resizableOptions );
        }
    },

    _setOption: function( key, value ) {
        var isDraggable, isResizable,
            uiDialog = this.uiDialog;

        if ( key === "dialogClass" ) {
            uiDialog
                .removeClass( this.options.dialogClass )
                .addClass( value );
        }

        if ( key === "disabled" ) {
            return;
        }

        this._super( key, value );

        if ( key === "appendTo" ) {
            this.uiDialog.appendTo( this._appendTo() );
        }

        if ( key === "buttons" ) {
            this._createButtons();
        }

        if ( key === "closeText" ) {
            this.uiDialogTitlebarClose.button({
                // Ensure that we always pass a string
                label: "" + value
            });
        }

        if ( key === "draggable" ) {
            isDraggable = uiDialog.is( ":data(ui-draggable)" );
            if ( isDraggable && !value ) {
                uiDialog.draggable( "destroy" );
            }

            if ( !isDraggable && value ) {
                this._makeDraggable();
            }
        }

        if ( key === "position" ) {
            this._position();
        }

        if ( key === "resizable" ) {
            // currently resizable, becoming non-resizable
            isResizable = uiDialog.is( ":data(ui-resizable)" );
            if ( isResizable && !value ) {
                uiDialog.resizable( "destroy" );
            }

            // currently resizable, changing handles
            if ( isResizable && typeof value === "string" ) {
                uiDialog.resizable( "option", "handles", value );
            }

            // currently non-resizable, becoming resizable
            if ( !isResizable && value !== false ) {
                this._makeResizable();
            }
        }

        if ( key === "title" ) {
            this._title( this.uiDialogTitlebar.find( ".ui-dialog-title" ) );
        }
    },

    _size: function() {
        // If the user has resized the dialog, the .ui-dialog and .ui-dialog-content
        // divs will both have width and height set, so we need to reset them
        var nonContentHeight, minContentHeight, maxContentHeight,
            options = this.options;

        // Reset content sizing
        this.element.show().css({
            width: "auto",
            minHeight: 0,
            maxHeight: "none",
            height: 0
        });

        if ( options.minWidth > options.width ) {
            options.width = options.minWidth;
        }

        // reset wrapper sizing
        // determine the height of all the non-content elements
        nonContentHeight = this.uiDialog.css({
                height: "auto",
                width: options.width
            })
            .outerHeight();
        minContentHeight = Math.max( 0, options.minHeight - nonContentHeight );
        maxContentHeight = typeof options.maxHeight === "number" ?
            Math.max( 0, options.maxHeight - nonContentHeight ) :
            "none";

        if ( options.height === "auto" ) {
            this.element.css({
                minHeight: minContentHeight,
                maxHeight: maxContentHeight,
                height: "auto"
            });
        } else {
            this.element.height( Math.max( 0, options.height - nonContentHeight ) );
        }

        if ( this.uiDialog.is( ":data(ui-resizable)" ) ) {
            this.uiDialog.resizable( "option", "minHeight", this._minHeight() );
        }
    },

    _blockFrames: function() {
        this.iframeBlocks = this.document.find( "iframe" ).map(function() {
            var iframe = $( this );

            return $( "<div>" )
                .css({
                    position: "absolute",
                    width: iframe.outerWidth(),
                    height: iframe.outerHeight()
                })
                .appendTo( iframe.parent() )
                .offset( iframe.offset() )[0];
        });
    },

    _unblockFrames: function() {
        if ( this.iframeBlocks ) {
            this.iframeBlocks.remove();
            delete this.iframeBlocks;
        }
    },

    _allowInteraction: function( event ) {
        if ( $( event.target ).closest( ".ui-dialog" ).length ) {
            return true;
        }

        // TODO: Remove hack when datepicker implements
        // the .ui-front logic (#8989)
        return !!$( event.target ).closest( ".ui-datepicker" ).length;
    },

    _createOverlay: function() {
        if ( !this.options.modal ) {
            return;
        }

        // We use a delay in case the overlay is created from an
        // event that we're going to be cancelling (#2804)
        var isOpening = true;
        this._delay(function() {
            isOpening = false;
        });

        if ( !this.document.data( "ui-dialog-overlays" ) ) {

            // Prevent use of anchors and inputs
            // Using _on() for an event handler shared across many instances is
            // safe because the dialogs stack and must be closed in reverse order
            this._on( this.document, {
                focusin: function( event ) {
                    if ( isOpening ) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if ( !this._allowInteraction( event ) ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        this._trackingInstances()[ 0 ]._focusTabbable();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        this.overlay = $( "<div>" )
            .addClass( "ui-widget-overlay ui-front" )
            .appendTo( this._appendTo() );
        this._on( this.overlay, {
            mousedown: "_keepFocus"
        });
        this.document.data( "ui-dialog-overlays",
            (this.document.data( "ui-dialog-overlays" ) || 0) + 1 );
    },

    _destroyOverlay: function() {
        if ( !this.options.modal ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( this.overlay ) {
            var overlays = this.document.data( "ui-dialog-overlays" ) - 1;

            if ( !overlays ) {
                this.document
                    .unbind( "focusin" )
                    .removeData( "ui-dialog-overlays" );
            } else {
                this.document.data( "ui-dialog-overlays", overlays );
            }

            this.overlay.remove();
            this.overlay = null;
        }
    }
});
```